# How to decompress a byte Array in Java

Tags: java, deflate

Can anybody tell me how to decompress a byte array?

Here is my code. I have been trying it for ages and it is giving me a `DataFormatException`.

```
byte bArray[] = new byte[tSizeOfTile];
input.read(bArray, offset, limit);

byte[] unComp = new byte[bArray.length + 100];

Inflater inflate = new Inflater();
inflate.setInput(bArray);
inflate.inflate(unComp, offset, bArray.length + 100);
inflate.end();
```

Comment: From where come those data in bArray ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one definite issue is that you're apparently using `InputStream.read` without checking the return value. That means you may have read less data than you expected to.

Also, you're trying to inflate into `unComp` *from* the offset, but with a maximum length being the same as `unComp.length`. That means if `offset` is anything other than 0, you could be trying to write past the end of the array.

Did you mean the offset to refer to the *input* array? I don't believe that's what it means. You should use `setInput` to *only* provide input data.

However, you could make all of this a lot easier for yourself by using `InflaterInputStream` instead of handling `Inflate` yourself.

Comment: i have also used so many Streams like input stream, SwappedDataInputStream and CountingInputstream so i do not want to use any other stream. i just do not know why its giving me DataFormatExeption. even this file is written using Zlib and Inflater class also use Zlib. so there should not be any problem.

Comment: @sajjoo: Are you sure that the original data is *actually valid*? Might you have a bug in the code which is compressing it?